# Center-align horizontally UI items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm attempting to create my first Android app and I'd like to horizontally align the items on screen and in rows.

I've tried setting the layout_gravity to center_horizontal as shown below however that doesn't appear to do anything. What am I missing?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
        app:boxedEdges="all"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"    
                android:rowCount="8"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:layout_row="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:layout_row="2"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serviceScore"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="50dp"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

UI:

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using `BoxInsetLayout`? A `ConstraintLayout` is the best solution for this kind of needs

Comment: Ah right. No particular reason however I think that was the default.

Comment: The `BoxInsetLayout` is thought for wearable devices, you're developing a mobile Android app or a wearable Android app?

Comment: try android:layout_gravity="center" instead of android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in GridLayout

Comment: @Niceumang Thanks. If you can post it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Bhav Well Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greet by Nice! Just add Gravity of layout **center** instead of **center_horizontal** of GridLayout.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```